# Map list of objects from client to server

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to map a list of objects from client to server, using MVC. On the server I see that list is populated with correct number of items, but properties are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code from client:

```
var listCAORAS = [];

    $('span.chkDelete input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function (i, obj) {
          var iORAS_KEY = $(obj).parent().attr('data-ioras_key');
          if (iORAS_KEY) {
            listCAORAS.push({ "iORAS_KEY": Number(iORAS_KEY) });
          }
        });

    $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url: '/OrderSupplier/DeleteCAORAS/',
          data: {
            listCAORAS: listCAORAS
          }          
        });
```

Server side:

```
public JsonResult DeleteCAORAS(List<DTO_CAORAS> listCAORAS)
{
}

public class DTO_CAORAS
{
  public int? iORAS_KEY { get; set; }

//many more properties here
}
```

Comment: Can you try running it with [FromBody]? Makes sense to work, as you are not currently passing it through the querystring, but from the body

Comment: Can you please add code example?

Comment: `public JsonResult DeleteCAORAS([FromBody]List<DTO_CAORAS> listCAORAS)`

Comment: Your javascript code does not seem to be creating any other properties, except your key, so why should the object on the server be any different?

Comment: The key is not mapped, that's the problem. There are many more properties, I've omitted them, because they are the same as iORAS_KEY. (integers)

Comment: Did you try simply `data: {
            listCAORAS
          }`

Comment: @BrunoMiquelin - [FromBody] didn't help, property is still empty.

Comment: @BrunoMiquelin FromBody is only needed for simple types. Complex types such as this are passed in the body automatically. Read the documentation.

Comment: @ADyson - I've tried only {listCAORAS}, but it's the same.

Comment: have you checked in the browser's network tools to see that the parameters are actually being populated properly in the client and all the correct data included in the request body?

Comment: @ADyson - yes, I've checked. Information is being passed to the server.

Comment: Can we see an example of that data then please. Would be good to check how jQuery is serialising it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default jQuery ajax `contentType` is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which means in order to bind to you model, the format of your data would need to be

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    data: { [0].iORAS_KEY: 1, [1].iORAS_KEY: 1, [2].iORAS_KEY: 1, ... }
});
```

i.e your object names need to have zero-based, consecutive collection indexers.

Note that if your view is correctly generated (i.e. your checkboxes are bound to a `bool` property and you have a hidden input for the `iORAS_KEY` property), then all you would need is

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    data $(yourForm).serialize()
});
```

To send an array of complex objects as you are doing, you must set the `contentType` to 'json' and stringify the data which instructs the `DefaultModelBinder` to use the `JsonValueProviderFactory` to deserialize the data to your model.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteCAORAS", "OrderSupplier")', // always use Url.Action() to generate the url
    ....
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ listCAORAS: listCAORAS })
});
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but listCAORAS is empty on the server side. I have even tried this: data: JSON.stringify(listCAORAS), but no difference. Exploring call from client looks like this: [{"iORAS_KEY":"180004590"},{"iORAS_KEY":"180004591"},{"iORAS_KEY":"180004592"}], which looks completely fine to me. How are you using '@Url.Action' in the javascript? I am getting an error, javascript doesn't recognize @Url.Action.

Comment: The data is fine and will bind correctly (and `data: JSON.stringify(listCAORAS),` will also work) based on the code you have shown. Off hand I cannot think what else you might have in your code that might be causing it to fail (but I'll do a test project shortly).

Comment: As far as `@Url.Action()` - is that script in an external file? (razor code is not parsed in external files)

Comment: Yes, it's external file.

Comment: OK, In that case, you would need to generate the url in the main view (a common solution is to use a `data-url="@Url.Action(...)"` attribute in the element your handling, and then in the script (for example) `$(someButton).click(function() { var url = $(this).data('url'); $.ajax({ url: url, .... }); })`

Comment: Have just tested this and it works fine (used the values from your first comment and .`listCAORAS` contained 3 `DTO_CAORAS` objects with the `iORAS_KEY` property correctly set.

Comment: The same technic and same code works also fine for me with other files (other methods). This is really strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167591/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-frenkyb).